# Visual studio debugger, dont stop website on stop debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

In previous versions of visual studio (or some setting I set years ago) when i stopped debugging a web application the actual IIS express instance would keep on running. I really like this behavior as it means the site is always running to tinker with while I'm editing my code/recompiling ect.

Since upgrading to VS 2013 this no longer seems to occur, when I stop debugging it also stops the IIS express app pool.

Does anyone know if there is a setting somewhere to change this behavior?

Comment: @JohnSaunders yeah thats not a bad idea, ill do that until i can find the setting

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One of the changes in VS2013 is to enable Edit and Continue by default in web application projects.  When you have Edit and Continue enabled, the VS debugger attaches invasively to the web server process (e.g. IIS Express). When you stop the debugger, this kills the IIS Express process as well. If E&C is turned off, the debugger does not use an invasive attach, which lets the debugger stop without killing the attached process.

You can find this in your project properties on the Web tab, under the Debuggers section.

Comment: Yeah that looks like whats doing it, much appreciated, i never use edit and continue anyway :)