# Prevent Visual Studio 2012 to stop my website when start debugging

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 web project. I am caching state in the application cache using the Ninject InSingletonScope.

Every time I start Visual Studio 2012 debugging (F5), it kills my web app and my app cache also.

Note that I use IIS and not IIS Express, and I don't use Edit and Continue (see [Visual studio debugger, dont stop website on stop debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831676/visual-studio-debugger-dont-stop-website-on-stop-debugging))

How can I prevent VS to stop my website every time ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pressing F5, try going to the menu: Debug -> Attach To Process and attach to w3wp.exe for the website that is hosted on IIS.