# Stop site when stopping debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I *think* this might be related to:

[Visual studio debugger, dont stop website on stop debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831676/visual-studio-debugger-dont-stop-website-on-stop-debugging)

And:

[How can I prevent Visual Studio 2013 from closing my IIS Express app when I end debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568762/how-can-i-prevent-visual-studio-2013-from-closing-my-iis-express-app-when-i-end)

In Visual Studio 2015, it appears that the behavior has changed again, and now when I stop my application in VS 2015, the website continues to run in IIS. That's not necessarily a problem, except when I then try to restart the website I get this error dialog:

[image]

And now I can't debug anymore (none of my breakpoints will be hit). Note that it absolutely is **not** a Release build and it debugged just fine the first time.

So how can I make it either not throw up that dialog and have debugging *just work*? Or else make it so that it stops the website in IIS when I stop the debugging (note: as far as I can tell "edit and continue" is still on for my project)

Answer (score 1):

Under the "Debug" menu, you have the ability to "Terminate All" and this is what I have been using to make sure that the IIS express instance is closed as well so I don't run into these issues.