# Stopping debugging stops the site (even with edit and continue off) in vs 2015 U2

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I recently installed VS 2015 Update 2.

In update 1 when i stop debugging a site running in IISExpress it does not stop the site.

There are a bunch of posts about enabling this behavior by turning off edit and continue.

- [IIS Express Immediately shutting-down running site after stopping web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376154/iis-express-immediately-shutting-down-running-site-after-stopping-web-applicatio)
- [How can I prevent Visual Studio 2013 from closing my IIS Express app when I end debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568762/how-can-i-prevent-visual-studio-2013-from-closing-my-iis-express-app-when-i-end)
- [Visual studio debugger, dont stop website on stop debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831676/visual-studio-debugger-dont-stop-website-on-stop-debugging)

Disabling edit and continue in update 2 no longer seems to provide this behavior, is there another work around to keep the site running when the debugger stops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visual studio 2015 update 3](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129) seems to have resolved this issue, happy days for me :)

Answer (score 11):

This appears to be a bug in Update 2 which [has been reported here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2562576/edit-continue-cant-be-disabled-which-causes-iis-express-to-stop-when-the-debugger-is-stopped) and hopefully gets enough upvotes so that MS takes action sooner than later.

In the meantime, you can Detach All from the debug menu instead of stopping the debug process.

[image]

If you want Detach All on your toolbar you can do so via the Tools, Customize menu and under commands, select the "Toolbar" radio option and choose the Debug from the pulldown.  Add a Command, choose "Debug" and select the Detach All command.

[image]

which then gives you this

[image]